# Use of GdiAlphaBlend

Tags: c++, mfc

I have 2 image unsigned char arrays which hold 4 channel RGBA images, I want to alphablend them, basically have an overlay.  How do I use GdiAlphaBlend to perform this.  I have looked online, and all the samples are not showing how to do this with direct images.

Can anyone point me to a sample or provide me one where I can see how to use this.

Thanks in advance!

This is the code

```
dcmem = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap( dcmem, 640, 480 );

bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bi.biWidth = 640;
bi.biHeight = 480;
bi.biPlanes = 1;
bi.biBitCount = 32;
bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bi.biSizeImage = ((((bi.biWidth * bi.biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3) * bi.biHeight;

bits = new char[bi.biSizeImage];
    // populate the data with 32 bits data

int ret2 = SetDIBits(dcmem, bmp, 0, bi.biHeight, bits, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

Then in OnDraw I did the following:

```
void CAlphaBlendingTestView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CAlphaBlendingTestDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    BLENDFUNCTION bf;
    bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    bf.BlendFlags = 0;
    bf.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

    BOOL test = AlphaBlend( pDC->GetSafeHdc(), 0, 0, 640, 480, dcmem, 0, 0, 640, 480, bf ); 
}
```

Comment: Simple. Create real images from your char arrays(perhaps look at the GdiPlus::Bitmap class), draw them to off-screen HDCs, then use GdiAlphaBlend to blend onto the target HDC.

Comment: I have added in my attempt to this, I dont see anything on the screen after doing this.  Also my AlphaBlend is returning false, so something I am doing in not right :(

Comment: haven't done anything like this for a while, and even then I always did it naked - i.e no MFC. I may not be of much help. Something I do notice, is that you're using `CreateCompatibleBitmap`, rather than `CreateDibSection`. Do you know that the bitmap creation/population succeeds? If you dont, I'd first try to `BitBlt` or `StretchBlt` the image to the destination. Once that succeeds, `AlphaBlend` is almost a drop-in replacement for `StretchBlt`. Ahhh! You don't appear to have used `SelectObject(dcMem, bmp)` anywhere. (bmp must be selected into a hdc before you can draw from/to it)